# How export DataTable to Excel with selected column

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

i am using tabletool for export datatable as excel which is working fine for export whole table now i want to export only selected column because some column having HTML entities (div,span, img ) inside table raw which causing issue.

i used following code for export whole table as excel

```
$(document).ready(function() {

         jQuery('#dashBoardTable').dataTable( {
                 "sScrollX": "200px",
                 "sScrollY": "200px",
                 "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

            } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need filter your table in another variable in jquery. This is a code that I used in a similar situation:

> function btnExportarExcel_onclick(sender) {
>               var trVisibles = '';
>
> ```
>         $('#tblBitacoraInterfazSAP > tbody > tr').each(function (i) { //Remove hidden rows
>             if ($(this).is(':visible'))
>                 trVisibles += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
>         });
>
>         var table = $('<table id="testTable"></table>');
>         table.append(trVisibles);
>
>         $(table).find('tr td').each(function (i) { //Remove hidden Columns
>             if ($(this).css('display') == 'none')
>                 $(this).remove();
>         });
>
>         //table variable is now filtering as you need
>     }
> ```

Hope this helps!